# Linked list method changes other list (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, polynomial-math

I've written a class which represents a polynom using a linked list (members in that list are objects of another class I made called PolyNodes). In that class I've written this method (this methods is supposed to get a paramater polynom and add it to existing polynom, returning the sum of the two polynoms **while not changing the paramater**):

```
public Polynom addPol(Polynom other)
{
   if (_head==null) //If the head is null, this polynom is empty and 
the other polynom becomes this polynom
   {
       _head=other._head;
       return this;
   }

   if(other._head==null) //if the polynom to be added is null, the
same polynom is returned
        return this;


   PolyNode curr=_head, curr2=other._head, prev=null, prev2=null;

   while(curr!=null && curr2!=null)
   {
      if(curr2.getPower()>curr.getPower())
      {     
          System.out.println("1 " + curr2.getCoefficient());
          PolyNode copy = new PolyNode(curr2.getPower() ,curr2.getCoefficient() );
          System.out.println("2 " + curr2.getCoefficient());
          copy.setNext(curr);
          if (prev==null)
                _head=copy;
          else
                prev.setNext(copy);
      }

      else if (curr2.getPower() == curr.getPower()) //If this polynom already
has a term with the same power, curr2's and curr's coefficients are summed up
      {
          curr.setCoefficient(curr.getCoefficient() + curr2.getCoefficient());
      } 

      //Moving the pointer to the next node in the polynom
      if(curr2.getPower()>curr.getPower())
      {
          prev2=curr2;
          curr2=curr2.getNext();
      }
      else if(curr.getPower()>curr2.getPower())
      {
          prev=curr;
          curr=curr.getNext();
      }
      else if(curr.getPower()==curr2.getPower())
      {
          prev2=curr2;
          curr2=curr2.getNext();
          prev=curr;
          curr=curr.getNext();
      }
   }

   if(curr2!=null) //If there are nodes left in other
   {
       for(;prev!=null;curr2=curr2.getNext()) //add them to this
       {
           PolyNode copy = new PolyNode(curr2.getPower() ,curr2.getCoefficient() );
           prev.setNext(copy);
           prev=curr2;
       }
   }

   return this;
}
```

For some reason (that is beyond me), the paramater polynom is changed as well when I use this method, when I try to keep it unchanged. I have no clue why. can someone please help me? I'm losing hope here.

Comment: I haven't read the code in deep, but you're changing curr2, which is initially the head of the parameter. Your problem is probably around that.

Comment: Could you please refer to me the line where I am changing curr2?

Comment: I don't know the lines exactly, but you have "curr2=curr2.getNext();" in 2 different places. Check for curr2 with ctrl+f and you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

you have this line:
`PolyNode curr=_head, curr2=other._head`
what you're doing there is giving a reference to _head and to other._head (the references are to their memory addresses).
so when you change of the objects, all of the objects with the same memory address will be changed as well.
if you want them not to be changed you need to allocate them with a new address in the memory.
you could do that:

```
PolyNode curr = new PolyNode(_head)
```

suppose you have a copy constructor.

Comment: Problem is I don't change curr2, the only methods I use on it are get methods.

Comment: yes, it changes curr2, but it only changes where it points to, not other._head